# Android XML Error - First App - NetBeans

Tags: android, compiler-errors, xml-validation

I've just started this evening into developing my first Android app and have come across an error that for the life of me I can't see where is coming from

When i launch my test app in the emulator it force closes with the error "The application Test App (psrocess Test.App) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

So far I've checked:
 The Android Development output - nothing untoward,launches fine and locates activity and intent
The Emulator output - nothing reported at all
The TestApp debug - reports BUILD SUCCESSFUL

I proceeded to then examine the main.xml used for the layout and on validation in NetBeans it reports "cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'LinearLayout'"

My main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<Button
android:id="@+id/used_cars"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/used_cars" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/used_vans"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/used_vans" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/dealers"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/dealers" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've trawled for info on how to fix this and can't find an answer
Could someone be kind enough to please advise if i'm missing something fundamental?

Thanks in advance
Barry

Comment: Logcat output would be great. Post that, we can better help you then.

Comment: Please give errors which you get.

Comment: I've turned logcat on but can't get it outputting any log info,is there anywhere handy to command it to log all actions the app makes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've went through the logcat info and found nothing so i decided to create a new app from scratch and copy over the info and it runs fine
If i do find any other info on what caused the issue i'll be sure to post it up
I can only put it down to a config error atm

Kind Regards

Barry